# Как в Python вставить символ в файл без удаления уже существующего символа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

На входе в текстовом файле: "январь февраль март блаблабла".На выходе должно быть: "январь1 февраль1 март1 блаблабла1". Иcпользую простую конструкцию для считывания из файла, а также write() и seek(). При использовании tell() выводится ошибка "telling position disabled by next() call".

```py
with open ('hello.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
                length=len(word)
                f.seek(length+1)
                f.write("1 ")


f.close()
```

Comment: Разбить файл на два, вставить символ и склеить обратно

Comment: Прочесть файл в память в строку, вставить символ и переписать файл целиком

Comment: s = 'январь февраль март блаблабла'
s = s.replace(' ', '1 ')
s += '1'
Сойдет?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно, оперативная память - более ценный ресурс, чем дисковое пространство.

Добавление информации в файл требует его полной перезаписи. Это более оптимально делать поблочно, с использованием временного файла, не занимая много памяти.

Предложенные ранее решения либо просто заменяют группы пробелов на одиночный пробел, либо дополнительно ещё и убивают разметку по строкам. Я считаю это неприемлемым.

Задача - добавить к концу каждого слова символ `1`. Нигде не сказано, что мы имеем право изменять что-то ещё.

Отсюда вытекает такое решение:

```
import re
import os
import tempfile

file_name = 'hello.txt'
# Определяем регекс снаружи цикла, 
# чтобы сэкономить ресурсы его компиляции снова и снова внутри цикла
find_regex = re.compile(r'([^\s])(\s|$)')

# Создаём временный файл в текстовом режиме в том же каталоге
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+t') as fout:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            # Добавляем 1 к каждому слову в строке, оставляя неизменным всё прочее
            fout.write(re.sub(find_regex, r'\g<1>1\g<2>', line))
    os.unlink(file_name)
    # Делаем hardlink для временного файла на имя нашего исходного файла
    # Когда временный файл автоматически удалится,
    # этот hardlink станет нашим новым файлом
    os.link(fout.name, file_name)
```

P.S. Это решение может быть доработано для учета пунктуации и других граничных условий

Answer (score -1):

```
new_text = ''
with open('hello.txt', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            word = word + '1'
            new_text = new_text + ''.join(word + " ")
    f.close()
with open('hello.txt', "w") as w:
    w.write(new_text)
    w.close()
```

Comment: Какой ужас. Вы этот код пробовали запускать?

Comment: Да, у вас не работает?

Comment: Работает. 1. Только заменяет все группы пробелов на одинарный и попутно избавляется от разметки по строкам. 2. Выполняет накопление строки путем конкатенации - очень дорого при длинных строках. 3. Загружает весь файл в память. 4. `close()` при использовании `with` - не нужен. 5. Не знал, что `for line in f:` - это разрешенная конструкция. Тут я ошибся. Всё равно, выглядит диковато...